# How to scan through multiple items in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to select all elements from the element table, but with an extra column stating whether or not ANY of their comments have admin status. A comment has admin status if the user that posted the status' admin column is 1.

I don't know how I'd scan through each comment for every element being queried.

In another part of the program, there is a query to draw down all comments of a single issue, and I was able to reason how to determine admin status there, but I can't think of a way to do it in a query that pulls down more than one issue.

```
SELECT comments.id, comments.elementID, comments.googleID, comments.time, comments.body, users.name, users.admin
FROM comments
LEFT JOIN users ON comments.googleID = users.googleID
WHERE comments.elementID = ? AND comments.approved = 1
ORDER BY comments.time DESC
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To know which elements have an comment from an admin user, you could simply do:

```
SELECT C.elementID, MAX(U.admin) AS admin
FROM comments C
LEFT JOIN users U ON C.googleId = U.googleID
WHERE C.approved = 1
GROUP BY C.elementID;
```

and then to get all elements with the additional admin column:

```
SELECT E.*, CASE WHEN A.admin = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS admin
FROM elements E
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    (SELECT C.elementID, MAX(U.admin) AS admin
     FROM comments C
     LEFT JOIN users U ON C.googleId = U.googleID
     WHERE C.approved = 1
     GROUP BY C.elementID) A
ON E.id = A.elementID
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a case expression with an `exists` predicate and a correlated subquery like so:

```
SELECT 
    e.*,
    CASE WHEN EXISTS (
       SELECT 1 
       FROM comments c
       JOIN users u ON c.googleID = u.googleID
       WHERE e.googleID = c.googleID AND u.admin = 1
    ) THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END AS AdminComment
FROM elements e;
```

Or you could express it using joins:

```
SELECT 
    e.*,
    CASE WHEN u.admin IS NOT NULL THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END AS AdminComment
FROM elements e
LEFT JOIN comments c ON e.googleID = c.googleID 
LEFT JOIN users u ON c.googleID = u.googleID AND u.admin = 1
```

Comment: For some reason yours is returning no for every post. The other guy's answer seems to be working. I'm not sure why.

Comment: @Connorelsea That's odd, but I guess maybe I made some bad assumption about your data. You can see the sample I tested with here: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0a6aa/1

Comment: @Connorelsea Oh, I think it might be because I did the join using googleID and not elementID perhaps

Comment: Yeah I changed one line to ` WHERE e.id = c.elementID AND u.admin = 1` and it worked.